# Django Is it efficient for DB to store uploaded files in model?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-uploads

I have a form and if I store the file using `form.save()`, is the entire file content stored in DB or just the file path?

Suppose I have hundreds of thousands or millions of files. Is it efficient to store all of them in DB because size of the table must be huge?

If I don't want to store them in database and simple upload and keep them in local file system, is there any way I could get the list of all file names? By storing them in database, I simply get that by:

```
AllDocument.objects.all()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the docs for the Django [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, by default django stores only paths to files in db, not the files themselves, so there is no problem to store even millions of file entries.
I do not think it is a good idea to store file paths somewhere else. At least, it will be more complex than using Django Manager.

Answer (score 2):

I think Djanga stores files in media or static root files, and the paths in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Doc.

> A local filesystem path that will be appended to your MEDIA_ROOT
>   setting to determine the value of the url attribute.

I think this can help you, to clarify the question.
A file-upload field . [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield)

> The file is saved as part of saving the model in the database, so the
>   actual file name used on disk cannot be relied on until after the
>   model has been saved.

[FileField and FieldFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile)